# Matrix Row and Column, Minima and Maxima

Tags: matrices, maxima-minima

Let's consider a $(m\times n)$ matrix with real values. Let's name some sets:

$S_1$: the set of all maxima of each column of the above matrix

$S_2$: the set of all minima of each row of the above matrix

I would like to compare $A=\min(S_1)$ and $B=\max(S_2)$.

My multiple tries have let me think that $A\geq B$ holds, but I cannot formally prove it. Any help with that formal proof? Or does there no comparative relationship between $A, B$ generally exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixed $i$ you have that
$$ \min_j a_{ij} \leq \min_j \max_k a_{kj}  $$
but then as the RHS does not depend upon $i$:
$$ \max_i \min_j a_{ij} \leq \min_j \max_k a_{kj}  $$
Examples show that there need not be equality.

Comment: How did you think of that first inequality? I am not asking how it is proven to be correct, but how you thought it.

Comment: Don't really know. But often when you work with sup and limsup you  establish some first inequality between sup/infs which is then preserved when taking another sup.

Comment: How did you get to the second inequality which is actually what we want to prove? I think that the inequality: $$\min_j a_{ij} \geq \max_k \min_j a_{kj}$$ for a fixed $i$ doesn't hold, but the reverse one ($\leq$) holds.

Comment: Not quite sure what you ask for? Anyway, given a function $f:A\times B \rightarrow {\Bbb R}$ you have $\inf_{y\in B} f(x,y) \leq \inf_{y\in B} \sup_{x\in A} f(x,y)$ and therefore:  $\sup_{x\in A} \inf_{y\in B} f(x,y) \leq \inf_{y\in B} \sup_{x\in A} f(x,y)$. It is not particularly related to matrices.

Comment: Well, the second inequality in the answer is exactly what we want to prove ($B\leq A$). How did you use the first inequality to derive the result of the second? There must have been another, maybe obvious inequality, that is being used in the midst. Sorry, but I am new to this field...

Comment: I see your question. But no, the RHS of the first is simply independent of $i$ so it is preserved by taking max over i.

Comment: Aha, now I do see it. Thanks a lot!